# Calendar Service: Store and retrieve events using PropertiesService

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

This code

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar Id");
var startTime = new Date(1850, 0, 1);
var endTime = new Date(2100, 0, 1);
var events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
Logger.log(events);
var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
sp.setProperty("events", JSON.stringify(events));
events = JSON.parse(sp.getProperty("events"));
Logger.log(events);
```

returns:

```
Info [CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent]
Info [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Why is that? What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why is that?**

`CalendarEvent` is a Google Apps Script class which events are instances of.

Checking property ownership and enumerability yields the following:

```
function stringified() {
  const event = CalendarApp.createAllDayEvent('Party', new Date());
  const eventToString = JSON.stringify(event);
  Logger.log(eventToString);                      // -> {}

  Logger.log(Object.keys(event));                 // -> []
  Logger.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(event));  // -> [toString,...]
  Logger.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(event));       // -> {}
  Logger.log(event.toString());                   // -> CalendarEvent
}
```

What does this tell us?

1. there are no *enumerable* props we can access (see `Object.keys()`).
2. there are *own* props (see `getOwnPropertyNames()`).
3. `CalendarEvent` inherits from `Object`<sup>1</sup> (see `toString()`).

Now, look at what `JSON.stringify()` does for objects (this is a description from MDN, but if you dig into the ECMAScript spec, you will see that `SerializeJSONObject` [operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-serializejsonobject) depends on abstract `EnumerableOwnPropertyName`):

*All the other Object instances (including Map, Set, WeakMap, and WeakSet) will have only their enumerable properties serialized*

Which leads us to your second question:

**What is wrong?**

Since there are no enumerable own properties, the serialization results in `"{}"`.

**What to do?**

It does not make much sense to store events with `PropertiesService` - you will quickly get into quota issues on larger event collections even if you figure a way to store. What does, is to store a *reference*, so how about using `getId()` method to store and `getEventById()` to retrieve?

**Sample**

```
//...get event somehow

const store = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

store.deleteProperty('events'); // demo only

const eventIds = store.getProperty('events') || '[]';

const id = event.getId();

const idList = JSON.parse(eventIds);
idList.push(id);
store.setProperty('events',JSON.stringify(idList));

Logger.log(store.getProperty('events'));
```

**What else to do?**

Use the Calendar API (don't forget to enablle it for your GCP project first by going to `Resources` -> `Cloud Platform project` -> `APIs and Services` -> `Library`). This API is a REST API that you can query with good old HTTP requests like that:

```
function listEvents() {

  const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('yourEmailHere');

  const endpoint = `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendar.getId()}/events`;

  const query = {};

  const preparedQuery = Object
    .entries(query)
    .map(param =>`${param[0]}=${param[1]}`)
    .join('&');

  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${endpoint}?${preparedQuery}`,{
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  });

  if(resp.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    //process the response
  }

}
```

Note that one would have to set the OAuth scope to be passed with the JWT token (obtained by `getOAuthToken()`). If there is an explicit scope list in application manifest (`oauthScopes` field of `appscript.json`), add `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly"` or a more appropriate one.

**Notes**

1. By this I mean that an instance of `CalendarEvent` has an object as its prototype due to prototypal inheritance.
2. Usage of `getUserProperties()` is preferrable to `getScriptProperties()` unless a script-wide setup is needed (see official guide in references). Script properties are shared across users and count toward quotas of the script owner.
3. To use the second sample, V8 runtime has to be [enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration) (from the question sample it is unclear if it is used).

**Reference**

1. Enumerability [explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) on MDN
2. `JSON.stringify()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on MDN
3. Calendar events `getId()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getid)
4. `getEventById()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventById(String))
5. Calendar API [reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference)
6. [OAuth scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar) for Google APIs
7. `PropertiesService` [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores)

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know what the `ScriptProperties` quota actually is? Why do you suggest `UserProperties` instead of `ScriptProperties`? Following your recommendation to store only references, I would have to change my function, which actually processes an array of `CalendarEvents`. I would need to distinguish whether the events come directly from the calendar (`getEvents()`) or from the storage (`getProperty()`). And wouldn't calling functions `getId()` and `getEventById()` for each individual event be inefficient?

Comment: Hi @Ben - my pleasure, hope this helped a bit. Yes, they are documented with other [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) under Properties (it may be more than enough for your needs, though). If you are worried about perfomance, try [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) and its batch methods - more boilerplate, but worth it. I mentioned `getEventById()` as an example, you can always use the [`getEvents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents(Date,Date,Object))

Comment: Why would you need to distinguish events from store and events from calendar, though? Btw, unless you have a really large eve t list (we are talking about `1e4` or so, I am not sure if you need an additional storage at all, a fetch on demand is just fine

Comment: Thank you for the [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) link! Could you give me an example for the use of _Calendar API and its batch methods_? Again, why do you suggest `UserProperties` instead of `ScriptProperties`? I would need to distinguish whether the events come directly from the calendar or from the storage because there is either a list of events (`getEvents()`) or a list of IDs (`getProperty()`). What do you mean by _a fetch on demand_? I need the storage because I run into timeout issues (exeeding maximum execution time).

Comment: Sorry, missed your q about `UserProperties` - this one is simple: first, if you use `ScriptProperties`, then everyone shares what's stored in it (this may be intentional in your use case - if so, just ignore) + quotas will count against user's quotas. Re:events - don't know your exact use case, confused by your wording - are you mixing these references in some way? Re:Calendar API - see link above for docs, but I can add a sample to the answer once get some spare time later today - its nothing too fancy :) Re:timeout - well, that's what plain old REST (Calendar API) comes in

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer as well as for the _Calendar API_ sample. "quotas will count against user's quotas" - Regardless of using `UserProperties` or `ScriptProperties`? "are you mixing these references in some way?" - Actually I don't.

Comment: Hi @Ben - oops, sems like I wasn't clear which quotas - `UserProperties` will count towards users' quotas, `ScriptProperties` - towards owner's (the latter are usually used for app-wide config). Re:refs - I meant is there a use case in your app where you might want to discern between events stored in props and those that aren't?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! "quotas" - Now I see. "refs" - No, there isn't. Except that I need to know which events have already been processed and which have not.

Comment: no problem! Hm, it depends on what the retention period is. If you just need to keep track during one session, simply keeping a list (with `Array`) or a hashmap with keys as ids and values as boolean flags will do (`const processed = { "some id" : 0 };`, and then `processed["some id"] |= 1`). If you need to share the list across sessions then you can use the `UserProperties` store as well. I think it warrants an extension to the question or a separate one to dive into details

Comment: Thank you! What does `|=` mean?

Comment: No problem! `|=` is a shortcut for bitwise ORing a value and rewriting a variable - in this case we take advantage of the fact that 0 | 1 = 1, and all subsequent 1 | 1 = 1. To reset, you can do `&=0`

Comment: Basically, the idea is to add even ids to the "hash map" (if you use ES6 features, `Map` will be even more suitable) - as soon as it is processed, corresponding key will remain at value `1`. If you want, you can persist the map in `UserProperties` and resume whenever you want. If you add a `lastUpdated : <id or date>` prop, you can reduce lookup times by skipping to the event or limiting query