# Google Spreadsheets Apps Script - Get selected non-consecutive range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I select cells `B1` and also `B3` in a spreadsheet (without selecting `B2` in the middle). I need a way (in Apps Script) to get the selected ranges (i.e. in this example `B1, B3`).

I thought that `getActiveRangeList()` is what I'm looking for. So I tried the following (in a macro):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRangeList = sheet.getActiveRangeList();
  console.log(activeRangeList); 
}
```

However this prints an empty dictionary to the console (`{}`). Am I missing something? Am I wrong about what `getActiveRangeList()` is supposed to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `console.log(activeRangeList.getRanges().map(range=>range.getA1Notation()));`

Comment: @TheMaster Wow, thanks! That works. Can you explain? I also tried `getRanges()` alone but that returned an empty list. What does the map function do and why is it needed?

Comment: see [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) . To log, the logged entry must be a string or array or object with enumerable properties. Although range is a object, it doesn't have enumerable properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script Calendar Service: Store and retrieve events using PropertiesService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017989/google-apps-script-calendar-service-store-and-retrieve-events-using-propertiess)