# Google Apps Script Calendar Service: How to store and retrieve CalendarEvents using PropertiesService?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017989/google-apps-script-calendar-service-store-and-retrieve-events-using-propertiess/61020821).

As this code

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar Id");
var startTime = new Date(1850, 0, 1);
var endTime = new Date(2100, 0, 1);
var events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
Logger.log(events);
var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
sp.setProperty("events", JSON.stringify(events));
events = JSON.parse(sp.getProperty("events"));
Logger.log(events);
```

returns:

```
Info [CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent, CalendarEvent]
Info [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

How to store and retrieve CalendarEvents (not only their IDs) using PropertiesService?

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of storing the events with script properties? PropertiesService is used for storing and retrieving information to be used later in the script. If you want to retrieve and use these events later, it's much more appropriate and efficient to just store the event IDs and later retrieve them via `getEvents()` and filtering the ones already in properties, instead of storing and retrieving all CalendarEvents properties. Also, if that's not possible, would you need to store all Event properties or just some of them?

Comment: Of course. I need to process a couple of hundred of `CalendarEvents`. As I run into timeout issues (exeeding maximum execution time) I have to divide them into chunks. So I store the number of `CalendarEvents` already processed in `ScriptProperties`. That would be it if I didn't want to take into account that additional `CalendarEvents` could be added during the execution of the script. That's why I want to store the `CalendarEvents` as well. Also retrieving something from `ScriptProperties` is much faster than calling `getEvents()` again. So what would you suggest?

Comment: _That would be it if I didn't want to take into account that additional `CalendarEvents` could be added during the execution of the script._ - The addition of additional events during the execution of the script could cause the index to shift and not all of the events selected at the start of the execution to be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Workflow:

I'm thinking the best option is to do the following:

- Retrieve event IDs from previously processed events, stored in Properties (variable `oldEventIDs`).
- Retrieve all events in the calendar with [getEvents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime-endtime) (variable `allEvents`).
- Filter the events in the calendar, removing the ones already in Properties (variable `newEvents`).
- After processing each new event, append the event ID to `oldEventIDs`.
- Store `oldEventIDs` in Properties.

#### Code sample:

```js
var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var oldEventIDs = sp.getProperty("events").split(",");
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar Id");
var startTime = new Date(1850, 0, 1);
var endTime = new Date(2100, 0, 1);
var allEvents = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
var newEvents = allEvents.filter(event => !oldEventIDs.includes(event.getId()));
newEvents.forEach(event => {
  // Event processing
  oldEventIDs.push(event.getId());
});
sp.setProperty("events", oldEventIDs.toString());
```

#### Notes:

- You have to call `getEvents` in each execution no matter what. I don't see how storing the events in Properties will let you avoid that. That's the method you use to get the events from the Calendar. In any case, I assume what's taking more time is the event "processing", about which no information was given.
- You would have to edit this sample so that the execution stops before reaching time limit.

#### Reference:

- [Calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime-endtime)
- [Class PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: Thank you very much! _I don't see how storing the events in Properties will let you avoid that._ Well, if I could store the events in `ScriptProperties` there would be no need to call `getEvents()` until all events would have been processed. Don't you understand?

Comment: @Ben You're welcome! About what you said, sure, if all events are already processed, there would be no need to call `getEvents`. But do you keep track of new events created in the calendar? How do you know no events were added if you don't call `getEvents`?

Comment: Well, there is a misunderstanding. First I want to select all `CalendarEvents`, then I want to process them in chunks. Only after all initially selected `CalendarEvents` have been processed, eventually added events should be considered in the next run.

Comment: @Ben I read it, but anyway I think it's much more efficient to call `getEvents` once per execution than to store the event properties into script properties (which event properties anyway? As @OlegValter said in the referenced question, Events don't have enumerable properties. If you have a list of event props you want to store, that would be more feasible, but anyway I don't see how that's better than calling `getEvents`).